# Power BI: How to get the sum value of current month using DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have revenue variable in my table that needs to sum up the value for the current month by creating a measure. How to do it using filter and calculate in Power BI Dax? Here's the below dax formula I tried:

```
Revenue Current Month = CALCULATE(SUM(Facttable[Sales]),FILTER('Date',EOMONTH('Date'[CalendarDate],0)= EOMONTH((today(),0)))
```